# TypeError: client.guilds is not iterable(14:29)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I was adding new features to my Discord Bot then suddenly the following problem has stopped me from completing my code ! ***( What is my mistake ? Where is my mistake ? How can I solve it ? )***

**The Problem :** 
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.guilds is not iterable(14:29)`

**My Code :**

```
    1: const { SettingProvider } = require("discord.js-commando");
    2: const File = require("./File.js");
    3: 
    4: module.exports = class JSONSettingsProvider extends SettingProvider {
    5:     constructor(path) {
    6:         super();
    7:         this.file = new File(path);
    8:         if (!this.file.exists) this.file.write({}, false, true);
    9:     }
    10: 
    11:     init(client) {
    12:         const data = this.file.read();
    13:         const id = bot.guild("689879529493233684");
    14:         for (const [id] of client.guilds) {
    15:             if (!data[id]) data[id] = {};
    16:             if (data[id].prefix && client.guilds.has(id))
    17:                 client.guilds.get(id).commandPrefix = data[id].prefix;
    18:         }
    19:         this.file.write(data);
    20:     }
```

Comment: What is the value of `client.guilds`?

Comment: Welcome Kawaki to the community, it looks like `client.guilds` is empty or not iterable object. You can update your question if you just want to know how to handle this error or give us more details on what is calling `init(client)`.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: "discord.js": "^12.2.0"

Comment: @VLAZ I don't know

Comment: @zzarbi        What details you want ?

Comment: Debug it? Log it? You're at the best position to check this. It's not possible for me or anybody else to do it.

Comment: Kawaki you can add a `if` condition to wrap around line 14-19 like so `if (typeof client.guilds == 'object' && typeof client.guilds[Symbol.iterator] == 'function')` but this will only handle your unhandled error. It might not fix your issue with discord.

Comment: @VLAZ What Do You Mean By What is the value of client.guilds ?

Comment: I'm A Beginner So Please Can You Explain What Is The Value That You're Talking About ?

Comment: zzarbi do you mean that I delete line 14 to 19 and paste the code you sent ?

Comment: zzarbi thank you it worked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `if` condition to wrap around line 14-19 like so `if (typeof client.guilds == 'object' && typeof client.guilds[Symbol.iterator] == 'function')`